# Python Flask - how to run subprocess (pass a command)?

Tags: python, flask

I have a running Flask app but want to pass any command via URL and make flask execute it on a host server and return results.

e.g. when running `curl localhost:5000/run/"ls -l"` (command is `ls -l`) -> expecting result:

```
.
..
file1
file2
etc..
```

So far I have:

```
import os

from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

@app.route('/run/<command>')
def run(command):
   return 'Run this %s!' % command


if __name__ == "__main__":  
    app.run(debug = True)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us what you already have for that `run` endpoint?

Comment: Added code with run endpoint.

Comment: are you sure you want this ? If this endpoint is ever exposed on the internet, it is the same as allowing anyone in the planet to type any command on your server. Even in closed networks there is some risk.

Comment: Yep, I am sure :)

Comment: Never mind, I got it..

Comment: This is a HUGE security hole. Use extreme caution!

Answer (score 3):

Just made it to work:

```
import os

from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"


@app.route('/run/<command>')
def run(command):
   out = os.popen(command).read()
   return (out)


if __name__ == "__main__":  
    app.run(debug = True)
```

Comment: Tangentially, `os.popen` is just a wrapper for `subprocess.Popen`. In fact, when this was originally posted, I believe `os.popen` was strongly deprecated, though the developers apparently gave up on getting rid of it, and instead replaced the deprecated function with a simple stub which redirects to the recommended one.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to pass commands in a JSON request instead of sending them as URL parameters:

```
from subprocess import Popen, TimeoutExpired, PIPE

from flask import Flask, jsonify, abort, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods=["POST"])
def index():
    req_json = request.get_json()

    if req_json is None or "command" not in req_json:
        abort(400, description="Please provide command in JSON request!")

    proc = Popen(req_json["command"], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True)

    try:
        outs, errs = proc.communicate(timeout=1)
    except TimeoutExpired:
        proc.kill()
        abort(500, description="The timeout is expired!")

    if errs:
        abort(500, description=errs.decode('utf-8'))

    return jsonify(success=True, message=outs.decode('utf-8'))

@app.errorhandler(400)
def bad_request(error):
    return jsonify(success=False, message=error.description), 400

@app.errorhandler(500)
def server_error(error):
    return jsonify(success=False, message=error.description) , 500
```

Save it to, say `server.py`, and run it:

```
$ FLASK_APP=server.py:app flask run
 * Serving Flask app "server.py:app"
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Request example:

```
$ curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"command": "ls -l"}' localhost:5000
{"message":"total 8\ndrwxr-xr-x 2 const const 4096 Jul 19 09:52 __pycache__\n-rw-rw-r-- 1 const const 1043 Jul 19 09:52 server.py\n","success":true}
```